# Find $x$ given $\sqrt{x+14-8\sqrt{x-2}}$ + $\sqrt{x+23-10\sqrt{x-2}} = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

If $\sqrt{x+14-8\sqrt{x-2}}$  + $\sqrt{x+23-10\sqrt{x-2}} = 3$, then what is the value of $x$?

Is there an easy way to solve such equation, instead of squaring on both sides and replacing $\sqrt{x-2}$ with a different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x+14-8\sqrt{x-2}}  +\sqrt{x+23-10\sqrt{x-2}} = 3$$
$$\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-2}-4})^2+\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-2}-5)^2}=3$$
Then 
$$|\sqrt{x-2}-4|+|\sqrt{x-2}-5|=3$$
Let $\sqrt{x-2}\ge5 (x\ge27)$. Then

$$\sqrt{x-2}-4+\sqrt{x-2}-5=3$$
$$\sqrt{x-2}=6$$

Let $\sqrt{x-2}\le4 (2\le x\le18)$. Then

$$4-\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x-2}+5=3$$
$$\sqrt{x-2}=3$$

Comment: Can you explain why you haven't covered the case for between 4 and 5? I'm going to guess the answer will be because no valid solution exists there but I'm wondering how you know that...

Answer (score 6):

It's not *so* bad; after you substitute $y=\sqrt{x-2}$ you will have
$$\sqrt{y^2 - 8y + 16 } + \sqrt{y^2 - 10y+ 25 } = 3$$
and you should be able to take it from here without any squaring of both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Condition: $x\geq 2$.

You have $$LHS = \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-2}-4)^2} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-2}-5)^2}.$$

So, if $\sqrt{x-2} < 4$, or $x<18$, then $$LHS = 4-\sqrt{x-2} + 5-\sqrt{x-2} = 9-2\sqrt{x-2} = 3 = RHS.$$

If $4 \leq \sqrt{x-2} < 5$, or $18\leq x < 27$, then $$LHS = \sqrt{x-2} -4 + 5-\sqrt{x-2} = 1 \neq 3 = RHS.$$

If $\sqrt{x-2} \geq 5$, or $x \geq 27$, then $$LHS = \sqrt{x-2}  - 4+ \sqrt{x-2} -5= 2\sqrt{x-2} - 9 = 3 = RHS.$$